# Grails Transient Fields

Tags: grails

Coming from a Rails background, I don’t really understand what transient means in Grails. I read this, http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html

So as it says

> "...In this case it doesn't make sense to persist this property..."

The guide is referring to `String getUpperCaseName() { name.toUpperCase() }`

I understand that `String name` will be picked up when trying to save to the database but why will grails bother with a getter method? It is a method to start with..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it "bothers" with a method is because of bean naming conventions where properties (in Java) are based on setters and getters. The pattern for identifying a "property" (through reflection) based on these are: `getXYZ()` and `setXYZ()` where `XYZ` is the property name in bean format (`name` becomes `Name` and `fullName` becomes `FullName`).

The reasoning was the fact these methods are `public` they can be reflected upon and derive properties from, since actual properties were typically `private` (for many good reasons). I still recall when this came about. (I'm getting too old)

That's why. Java.

It's not a Grails thing. It's a Java thing. You can read more about the  [JavaBean specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) if you want a deeper understanding of the technologies you are using..